# Relative Path FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, path, log4j, relative-path

i have created two different java projects on project is depend on other and

like A project and B project A project has logs folder and in log4j.xml i have given relative path of log files 
now i am using A project as api in B project and i have created executable jar of B project when i am calling B it is giving me FileNotFoundException.

Please suggest me .............

```
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ..\Framework\logs\log.log (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.openAppend(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:273)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:152)
    at org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender.activateOptions(DailyRollingFileAppender.java:206)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:247)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseAppender(DOMConfigurator.java:210)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByName(DOMConfigurator.java:140)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByReference(DOMConfigurator.java:153)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseChildrenOfLoggerElement(DOMConfigurator.java:415)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseRoot(DOMConfigurator.java:384)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parse(DOMConfigurator.java:783)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:666)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:616)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:602)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:460)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:113)
    at com.netapp.ca.framework.logger.LogImpl.<init>(LogImpl.java:35)
    log4j:ERROR Either File or DatePattern options are not set for appender [allLog].
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
```

Comment: Are the log files included in your A project jar? They must be compiled inside your jar. Take a look at your jar. But what are you trying to do? Do you want to generate logs in a folder inside a jar? Or you just want to reference some files for your logs inside the A project?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are executing from a jar, and therefore (of course) the path is wrong because you can't save log files (normally) within a jar.

I've had the same problem and worked it out writing the following method to receive a path where my application can work:

```
String applicationPath = this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
applicationPath = applicationPath.replace('\\', '/');
if (applicationPath.startsWith("file:")) applicationPath = applicationPath.substring(5);
if (applicationPath.contains(".jar")) {
    String[] parts = applicationPath.split("/");
    applicationPath = applicationPath.replaceAll(parts[parts.length - 1], "");
}
```

I don't know how your application is structured but I think this code could help you. Simply write the "applicationPath" to the console and you know what's wrong with the path. I bet it is something like the jar-problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you are trying to do, but in simple terms it appears that Log4J cannot find the logfile which you specified in the `log4j.xml` config.

It is best to use absolute paths when specifying the logging directory for Log4J, but if you insist in using relative paths then make sure you are absolutely sure which directory is the "working directory" for your application.

You can log the working directory for your application with the following code (put this in your Java executable, `main` method):

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

Once you know the working directory, you can update the logfile path in your `log4j.xml` config.

Comment: thanks for that please can you give me this complete demo for system property. frend i am getting problem when i am creating jars and executing this app via jar otherwise by eclipse its working fine with relative path.

Comment: Your executable jar, project B, should contain a class with a `main` method. Place the print statement on the first line of your `main` method.